# dashboard menu is not seen in my admin panel wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

in my wordpress admin panel my dashboard menu in doesn't seen and when i want to login with wp-admin/ url that show this error to me " You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page. "

Comment: Seems like you're trying to login to wp-admin with an account that isn't an Administrator. Try looking in your database and seeing what category your user account is

Comment: my user account is admin when i fill login form then that error shows to me and im put static url such as wp-admin/plugins.php  it works , and also dashboard menu is does not show

Comment: Check your database your user account name can be anything, it's the category that's important. Do you have any plugins that are active? Try disabling them all, and then trying again.

Comment: i removed all of my plugins but its not works too

Comment: Again, check your database.

Comment: i don't have any problem with my accounts it works good just in my admin panel dashboard menu not seen and when i put .../wp-admin/index.php that error comes to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check database table wp_user
Find the ID of the user you are logging in with

Check database table wp_usermeta
where user_id is the Id of your user, make sure wp_capabilities is set to---

a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}